# Is it possible to connect through session manager to the instance using SSH from an external source like my desktop. And if so, how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, architecture, system, putty

I was able to connect too. I have been clicking through the Session Manager console. Pretty neat.
The next question I have with this - I *think* we should be able to connect using SSH from an outside SSH client. Meaning, I have a client on my desktop (The client I use is called Putty). So, is it possible to connect from desktop through session manager instead of having to login to the console?

**The end goal for this:** In production we have a linux system that an outside marketing company connects to using SSH. Right now, we just have that system accessible to them through a public IP address. It would be more secure to use Session Manager within Systems Manager to do their connections. Session Manager would also allow us to log all activity on the system while they were logged in. But we'll worry about that later.

Just need to know if it's possible to connect through session manager to the instance using SSH from an external source like my desktop. And if so, how?

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: it should be possible if you install the SSM Agent, sure. You should probably ask this on ServerFault though

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to use **Session Manager** to connect to an EC2 instance in a **private subnet**, but *without* using the AWS management console, then you can use the AWS CLI command: [start-session — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/start-session.html)

> Initiates a connection to a target (for example, an instance) for a Session Manager session. Returns a URL and token that can be used to open a WebSocket connection for sending input and receiving outputs. `start-session` is an interactive command that **requires the Session Manager plugin** to be installed on the client machine making the call.

This way, you can provide them access to the private instance without granting them console login credentials. (Give them an Access Key and Secret Key, but not a Username and Password.)

It is also possible to use [Port Forwarding](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-port-forwarding-using-aws-system-manager-sessions-manager/) on a Session Manager session to expose port 22 for use with a normal SSH client, but that is a little more complex.